# SwiftUI EnvironmentObject not available in View initializer?

Tags: swiftui

I passed the environmentObject appSettings into my view successfully. I can use it to modify my font and the picker in my View.  But if I try to access an environmentObject published variable in the view init() it crashes with:

```
Thread 1: Fatal error: No ObservableObject of type AppSettings found.
A View.environmentObject(_:) for AppSettings may be missing as an ancestor of this view.
```

Are there special rules about using an environmentObject in a custom SwiftUI View initializer?

Here's the start of my view code.  The environmentObject is appSettings.  If I comment out line 2 in my initializer and uncomment line 3 the app works.  Note that I use "appSettings.interfaces" successfully later in my Picker.

```
struct CaptureFilterView: View {

@State var etherCapture: EtherCapture? = nil
@EnvironmentObject var appSettings: AppSettings
@Binding var frames: [Frame]
@State var captureFilter: String = ""
@State var error: String = ""
@State var numberPackets = 10

@State var interface: String = ""
init(frames: Binding<[Frame]>) {
    self._frames = frames
    self.interface = appSettings.interfaces.first ?? "en0" //CRASH HERE
    //self.interface = "en0"  //uncomment this and comment line above to make app "work"
}
var body: some View {
    HStack() {
        ...
        Picker(selection: $interface, label: Text("")) {
            ForEach(appSettings.interfaces, id: \.self) { interfaceName in
                Text(interfaceName).tag(interfaceName)
            }
        }
```

Here's where I create my top-level content view in my AppDelegate.swift

```
        let contentView = ContentView(showCapture: true).environmentObject(appSettings)
```

And **just to be sure** I also pass on the environmentObject when creating my CaptureFilterView in my top level ContentView.  This is not necessary and does not change the behavior.

```
            if showCapture { CaptureFilterView(frames: self.$frames).environmentObject(appSettings) }
```

For reference here is the top of my appSettings:

```
class AppSettings: ObservableObject {
    @Published var font: Font
    @Published var interfaces: [String]
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> SwiftUI EnvironmentObject not available in View initializer?

**Yes, SwiftUI EnvironmentObject not available in View initializer.** Why? It is simple - it is injected **after** object initialiazation.

Let's consider how it is done on example of above `ContentView`:

```
let contentView = ContentView(showCapture: true).environmentObject(appSettings)
```

so what's going on here? Here

1. instantiation & initialisation of value for the type ContentView

```
let newInstance = ContentView.init(showCapture: true)
```

2. calling function `func environmentObject()` on `newInstance` injected `appSetting` property

```
let contentView = newInstance.environmentObject(appSettings)
```