# How to work around swiftUI environmentObject not available in view initializer?

Tags: ios, swiftui

I have read [SwiftUI EnvironmentObject not available in View initializer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60514448/swiftui-environmentobject-not-available-in-view-initializer) which says that environmentObject is not available for use in `init()`

That being said, what would be a alternative way of calling a method in an environmentObject when the view appears?

Should I have the parent of this view call that method when this view is triggered to show?

Comment: You can use `.onAppear`. Also, remember that `init` is called often by SwiftUI, and isn't an indicator of the lifecycle of the view. Hard to say more without seeing what you're trying to do.

Comment: The env object should be available in the `body` of the view. Is it possible to use that from there in your case?

Comment: It is not clear what do you want to solve or achieve... would you provide your case in code?

Comment: Actually all your input has helped me out.  I have a ChatView that when it appears, I want to call my real time manager's `loadChannel()`.  As for why I put it into environmentObject, I did this because I need some functionalities from this real time manager this across the app.  Do you think I should still put this into the .onAppear since that should be only called once?